# How to show content of sql view with for each in progress language

Tags: sql, progress-4gl, openedge

Help! I trying to see my sql view content without using `select * from viewTest`.

I rather prefer using progreess like:

```
For each viewTest No-lock:

disp viewTest.

end.

With sql command it's working but i'd prefer for each.
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The 4GL does not know about SQL views.

The SQL that you can access from within the 4GL engine is SQL-89.  It exists primarily as a "marketing check box".  Do not try to use it for any serious purpose.  You will only regret it.